# How can an "unofficial" book avoid copyright issues?

Tags: copyright

I was in a bookstore today and I saw a coloring book called "Tolkien's World" which was based on characters from The Lord of the Rings and other works by JRR Tolkien. On the back cover, it said:

> This book is unofficial and is not authorised by the Tolkien Estate or HarperCollins Publishers.

How can the author and his/her publisher get away with that? Surely the publication of the work is going to infringe on the copyright of the Tolkien Estate and HarperCollins? I would have expected publication of the work to have drawn a lawsuit, but it's clearly been in print for a couple of years.

Disclaimer - I have no background in law.

Comment: What's the nature of the book?  Fiction?  Commentary on Tolkien's works?

Comment: Its a coloring book. Black and white images that you can color in, but containing specific references to Tolkien characters.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that you said that.  In that case I have no idea.

Comment: Well, first off, if the Tolkien estate doesn't *notice* the book...

Comment: From another stack; [How can these unlicensed books about Middle Earth get published legally?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179267/how-can-unlicensed-books-about-middle-earth-get-published-legally/179284#179284)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered more completely [over on SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179284/42547). The user over there lays out a number of points explaining that the works are "substantially transformative". The author of these works goes to some effort to build a case for this substantial transformation in his prefaces and notices in the derived work as well.

Answer (score -2):

There was a guy I knew used to sell cocaine. Selling cocaine is illegal, arguably, *more* illegal than copyright violation. How could he get away with that?

In both cases, the answer is the same: don’t get caught.

Comment: This is a very poor answer. It stretched credulity that the Tolkien Estate are unaware of the book.

Comment: Dale M, I'm surprised at you. You normally give such in-depth and insightful answers. You know we don't do one liners here!

Comment: @LateralTerminal we all have off days

Comment: It should be whether the answer is correct, not its length. It's sad you two would vote this down.